# Security Error Calling REST Web Service from Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, glassfish-3

I created a proxy RESTful web service in Glassfish 3.1.2 for an Ajax application.  I define a RESTful web service in Glassfish that then calls an external RESTful web service.  I use the Jersey Client classes to call the external web service:

```
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);          
    MultivaluedMap queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();


    queryParams.add("dtype", datatypeStr);
    queryParams.add("bbox", boundingBoxStr);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(callURL);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(callURL);

    ClientResponse response =  webResource.queryParams(queryParams).accept("application/atom+xml").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

The above code works in a standalone client and it also works in Glassfish 3.1, but in Glassfish 3.1.2 it fails with an unauthorized error.

So I guess I have two questions, is using the Jersey client jars the best way to create a proxy web service in Glassfish? And what changed in Glassfish 3.1.2 that is causes the unauthorized error.

I read that [CSRF protection](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/2012/03/glassfish-3-1-2-rest-security-and-the-jersey-client/) has been added to Glassfish 3.1.2, but that should only effect clients calling RESTful web services deployed to Glassfish, not calling external web services from Glassfish.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: please update with the error too.  it makes things less ambiguous.

Comment: any progress with this?